# .htaccess redirect without change url working in localhost but not working in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Following is my code in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^category/.*?/cat_(\d+)$ http://www.domainname.com/site/viewproducts.php?catid=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is when I visit

`http://www.domainname.com/site/category/Food_Items/cat_<passed_id>`

the address bar is changed to

`http://www.domainname.com/site/viewproducts.php?catid=<passed_id>`

Its just working fine in localhost without changing address bar, but in server it working but address bar is changed. My web server running in unix and localhost running in windows.

I can't find the answer. Plz somebody help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing the `RewriteRule` as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^category/.*?/cat_(\d+)$ viewproducts.php?catid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: actuall all my codes are placed in "public_html/site" folder.. so that i put the base to '/site'... eventhouth i changed to '/' same problem continues

Comment: can i post my site url here?

Comment: i changed to 'RewriteBase /' in .htaccess in server.. still not workin